# What is the error in my consonant/vowel replacer?

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I am making a small program.You enter a string then my program outputs the string except where a was a consonant is now a "C" and for vowels a "V".Why does it output wrong when I enter "Elicopter" and maybe other words?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const char con[]={'b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z','B','C','D','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
const char vow[]={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};
const char car[]={'!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','?','+','-','_','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
int scon=sizeof(con)/sizeof(con[0]);
int svow=sizeof(vow)/sizeof(vow[0]);
int scar=sizeof(car)/sizeof(car[0]);
string x;
int i,j;

getline(cin,x);

for(i=0;i<x.length();i++){
    if(x[i]==' '){
        cout<<" ";
    }

    else{

    for(j=0;j<scon;j++){
        if(x[i]==con[j]){
            cout<<"C";
            break;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<svow;j++){
        if(x[i]==vow[j]){
            cout<<"V";
            break;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<scar;j++){
        if(x[i]==car[j]){
            cout<<x[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
}



    return 0;
}
```

I am sorry my code is a mess.

Comment: You have `'i'` in both `con` and `vow`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and programming in general. We all write code that doesn't work the way we want. To figure out the problem requires debugging. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started. Using these tricks, you can find where your code doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: This is really crying out for `std::vector` rather than doing math with `sizeof` and guessing how many entires there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the obvious already pointed out by @1201ProgramAlarm (`'i'` being in the list of consonants), there is lots of very unidiomatic code in there -- the way you would code in C, and rather low quality C at that (no offense).

While no code is ever perfect, perhaps you might benefit from having a look at the same (well, a pretty similar...) program, written in actual C++. Just to get an idea what you *could* do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <locale>

// "using namespace" is a habit that tends to get in the way
// once you start including headers from multiple namespaces,
// so while it has its place in quick one-shots, personally I
// got into the habit of fully qualifying.

int main()
{
    // This is, of course, very non-international, but I will
    // let this slide and not drag the ICU library into this...
    std::string_view const consonants { "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" };
    std::string_view const vowels { "aeiou" };
    std::string input;

    // while instead of if allows you to make multiple lines of
    // input. <Ctrl>-D to end the program (<Ctrl>-Z <Enter> on
    // Windows).
    while ( getline( std::cin, input ) )
    {
        // Range-For eliminates the need for loop counters / iterators
        for ( auto const c : input )
        {
            if ( consonants.find( std::tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( c ) ) ) != std::string::npos )
            {
                std::cout << 'C';
            }
            else if ( vowels.find( std::tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( c ) ) ) != std::string::npos )
            {
                std::cout << 'V';
            }
            else if ( std::isprint( static_cast<unsigned char>( c ) ) )
            {
                // Not exactly the same as your list of digits
                // and punctuation, but similar, and showing the
                // use of character types. isprint() is also true
                // for ' '.
                std::cout << c;
            }
        }

        // std::endl ensures a flush of the write buffer
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad. `consonants` and `vowels` should be `const string_view`s. `c` should be `const`. [`tolower` _needs_ a cast to `unsigned char`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower). A binary search of `consonants`/`vowels` would fix your algorithmic complexity problem (though, arguably, at this scale, the extra maths may not be worth it).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Good points. Didn't get into the "groove" with string_view yet. The omission of the cast is embarassing; the very last comment I posted was about telling somebody else that, and then I forget it myself. :-D

Comment: [It was about twenty comments ago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60281/devsolar?tab=activity), but I'll accept your tale ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: You haven't seen the ones that got deleted again...

Comment: Hah, fair. Then you've posted it at least twice, and have even less excuse :P